# Graph connectivity after deleting an f-factor

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G(V,E)$ be an undirekted $k$-vertex-connected, $k$-regular graph
and let $F$ be an $f$-factor of $G$ consisting of a set of $f$-vertex-connected components, $f<k$.

> **Question:**
>   what is the vertex-connectivity of $G\setminus F$, is it $k-f$, resp., what is the highest lower bound on the resulting vertex-connectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make $G$ from two highly-connected pieces joined by a matching of $k$ edges.  It has connectivity $k$.  Now take $F$ to be a perfect matching that includes the edges of the cut.  $G\setminus F$ is then disconnected.  So there is no general lower bound except 0.